# How can I see the redirects made by the browser in other tabs?

Tags: html, download

How can I see the redirects made by the browser in other tabs? For example when downloading a file opens in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use chrome you can log data to disk.

chrome://net-export/

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for how to redirect an href to another tab you have to add `target="_blank"` to your href like this:

`<a href="newpage.html" target="_blank"> Click to Go To new Tab </a>`

If you aren't asking for that please be more clear with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment to ask you what kind of solution you would like. So I'll post some of them here.

1. I just wanna know

If you just want to know what's happening, we may open your developer tool on your browser (e.g `Ctrl+Shift+I` or `F12` on chrome) and go the network section. You'll see everything that is happening.

2. I want to do this automatically.

Well, you can go check [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests), how to intercept the HTTP requests.

But maybe [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/242138/how-to-track-url-redirects-in-the-browser), might help you having a bigger picture.

Hope it'll help you.